# Send image with Http attach results in $request->files empty

Tags: file-upload, guzzle, laravel-9

I am trying to send a file with Laravel `Http` client. The problem is that in the controller, the `$request->files` array is always empty.

This is the code I use for the call:

```
$file = UploadedFile::fake()->image(fake()->slug(1) . '.png', 600, 600);

$response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $bearerToken,
    ]
)
->attach(
    'file', $file
)
->post($url,
    [
        'name' => 'my-name',
        'test' => true,
    ]
);
```

While, in the controller I just do:

```
Log::info($request->all());
Log::info($request->files->all());
Log::info($request->file('file'));
```

And I have empty values for both `$request->files->all()` and `$request->file('file')`.